# What am I doing wrong with this AJAX request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX, so sorry if this is simple, but I've looked all other the place and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

When I swap the $_POST['name'] to an actual value, for example - $name = 'apple'; - everything works fine.  However when I try to get the value from the AJAX post request in the php file like below, it doesn't work.  Help!  Thanks in advance.

PHP

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE email = 'test' AND item = '$name' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($result){

                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


                    echo json_encode($row);


                } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.option').on('click', function(){
    var name = $(this).val();
        $.post('ajax.php', {name: name}, function(data) {

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            var desc = obj[7]
            $('#name').val(desc);
        });
    });
    });
```

HTML

```
Item: <input type = "text" id = "name" size = "6">
    Description: <input type = "text" id = "name" size = "6">
    Qty: <input type = "text" id = "name" size = "6">
    Price: <input type = "text" id = "name" size = "6">
    Discount: <input type = "text" id = "name" size = "6">
    Account: <input type = "text" id = "name" size = "6">
    Tax Rate: <input type = "text" id = "name" size = "6">
    Amount: <input type = "text" id = "name" size = "6">
    <div class = "option">Apple</div>
```

Comment: check you get the correct result with var_dump($_POST['name']);

Comment: can you post the html code as well

Comment: Do you get any error? Or anything at all?

Comment: Yeah, the var_dump just says null.

Comment: Kinda wonder if `name` isn't a reserved word.  I'd think about adjusting that if nothing else is jumping out.

Comment: your sql is prone to mysql injection! you've not properly escaped `$name` before using it in the query.

Comment: Ha thanks; yeah i know, covered that topic; this was just to get a demo to get an understanding of ajax

Comment: your ajax was fine.. it was just your use of jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple is not the value of your div with class option, it is the inner html.

Your code is checking the value of the element clicked when an object with class option is clicked. To see correct behavior with current code, change

```
var name = $(this).val();
```

to

```
var name = $(this).html();
```

I doubt this is how you will want your final solution to look, but always be careful about what exactly the methods you are using return.

edit: id's should be unique, I would recommend strongly against using the same id for your input objects.

Comment: You're doing well for a beginner, but there are a lot of subtleties and best practices for html jquery and css. While I am a terrible hypocrite and suspect I work and learn much like you do, I strongly recommend reading some tutorials and guides as to how to properly work with html jquery and css.

Comment: Cheers, will do